# How to extract JSON serialization from HTML? C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json.net

First. My apology for being a JSON newbie. I suppose my ignorance makes it difficult for me to ask an accurate question. No worries, I will edit and clean up this post after clarity is reached.

I have some html from a 3rd party website that has JSON data that I would like to extract. I've written unit tests that serialize/deserialize the JSON data to C# class. However, my offline test input file is generated by a manual copy paste operation: I opened the *.html source, found the JSON serialization data string, and copy pasted to an offline file. I then used it as input to my unit test. It works great.

This manual copy/paste operation I'd like to make automatic.

Currently the URL that I am using returns HTML - and the JSON data is buried in the `HtmlDocument` somewhere - and I haven't the foggiest how to determine what the direct JSON query url might be, or how to discover it. It would be ideal to know how to obtain this.

With this background information explained I'll now ask my question(s).

Conceptually I think there might be two questions to ask. There should be only one, but there in lies my ignorance: I'm not certain which question is the better to ask, or if the two I post below are even in the ballpark. My hope is that you understand what I'm asking from a conceptual view point and after I reach some understanding I can modify it to a more technical/accurate viewpoint. Please bear with me.

**Q1: When working with a 3rd party website, how does one determine what the GET string should be to directly request JSON object?**

This seems like the ideal solution but I do not understand the process of determining how the GET request should be constructed. I have barely scratched the surface of using a Inspector tool in Firefox to investigate html. Using this tool to find the JSON request URL string (for a GET) is a mystery to me.

**Q2: When working with a 3rd party website, how does one navigate the Html to find the node where the JSON string can be extracted?**

And this is a backup question. If the answer is that "no, you cannot directly determine the JSON URL GET string", the backup is to traverse the Html and locate the element that contains the JSON data string.

**Example of the html:** (heavily truncated to fit here in this post)

```
...lots of html, followed by:

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
         function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
         gtag('js', new Date());
         gtag('config', 'UA-6441790-1');
    </script>
    <script>
      var result = {"teams":["tigers","sharks","destroyers","nerfs"]};
    </script>

...lots more html, followed by EOF.
```

And the JSON data is encapsulated in the `var result` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get HTML as text then use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML and find script tags. Then you need create your own code that will find correct script tag out of many. Maybe by matching if it's content starts with `var result =`. Then you need parse that JSON as text with your own code. Maybe getting everything after `var result =` and trimming out last `;` is enought here. Then you can use JSON.NET to deserialize that JSON if needed.

Comment: This worked...its' just not elegant. Hmmm. I will keep the question open for a while longer to see if I get any other answers. I was hoping for something more elegant. The issue with this solution is that if the regex stops working (for example, some day in the future they change it to 'var result2=' all of a sudden my static regex won't work, because it doesn't match anymore) etc.

Comment: @sapbucket that's the reality you have to live with if they don't provide you with an api. You need something match what data to parse from the page and they could also change that JSON data to different format. Are you sure they don't provide an api where you could fetch this data? Maybe you could contact them and ask?

Answer (score 0):

If I haved understood you correctly:

1. If you want to obtain the HTML dynamically(in code) you can use HttpClient https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2 and make just simple GET request. It will return result (which in this case will be HTML). On client side you can use jQuery's load http://api.jquery.com/load/
2. Regarding Q1: if someone wants to provide some data for others they simply expose and API (ex. using REST). If it is that case they also provides some API references. ex. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs . API's provide data in comfy way, using some standarized format ex. JSON/XML. Common practice is to allow the requestor to specify the format he would like to recive (using Accept Mime Type).
3. Regarding Q2: You can not simply navigate the html to obtain the data. API's documentation specifies urls/formats/expected output. On the other hand when you request for HTML or try to traverse through html to obtain data you have no certainty of the result. One day the html can be changes which will result in not finding the data you would like to extract. So extracting data from respone's html is not a good practice. If someone does not expose an API that may mean they do not want to? Of cours if you really badly want that data you make extractions like described but it is burdened with possible mentioned errors and inconveniences while extracting the data.

Comment: I agree I do not want to traverse the HTML. For example, it seems like a REGEX can be used to extract the string, but this is very delicate. Any changes to the HTML can break the regex. However, the 3rd party I'm working with is definitely exposing the JSON data for public usage. But there is no documentation. They probably think it is so easy to figure out that they don't explain it. This is such a simple yet non trivial problem. There must be an elegant solution. I will review the links you posted.

Comment: Can you share the 3rd party link or for some reasons no? Maybe they are hosting some self-description api? .NET have something called swagger https://swagger.io it builts "documentation" along with your code. If they really have approach that assumes they API is simple I would be suprised. Even though they are some common patterns in building API's there is a full arbitrariness in doing it

Comment: I'd rather not publicly disclose their website. However, I do have an offline html file. I'm not sure if it will help much. I'm also not sure how to attach here on my SO post. There doesn't seem to be an option for attaching files. It's 255kB. Too large to copy paste.

Comment: HTML will not help much. I was wondering how does it looks like and if I could somehowe discover their api but in that case i can't help more, sorry